# Is there any translator plugin for Android (Eclipse)?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, translate

I want to translate my resource strings and create new resources for other languages.

Is there any translator tool for Android or a plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Is this maybe something for you?

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.sequoyah.localization.android.help%2Ftopics%2Ft_localize-all-string-translating.html

Answer (score 0):

If you right click strings.xml and I assume we are talking about an android app you have the translate option. However you must be setup for Google play account.